# Checkbox not bind in model binding in ASP.NET MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Checkbox not bind in model binding,

the hidden input in bind correctly but only checkbox not work

that is my class:

```
public class SelectedIDsViewModel
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

}
```

and that is checkbox:

```
<form asp-action="DeleteAll" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ArticleDetails.Count(); i++)
{

      <input name="@("ddd["+ i + "].IsChecked")" type="checkbox" />
      <input name="@("ddd["+ i + "].ID")" 
        value="@Model.ArticleDetails[i].ArticleID" type="hidden" />
}

</form>
```

and that is my method action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteAll(List<SelectedIDsViewModel> ddd)
{

     return View();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't render `<input />` elements manually. Use `@Html.CheckBoxFor` instead.

Comment: yes, it worked with me, thank you,

Comment: can you answer my question so i can mark your reply as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag helpers as well like this

```
<form asp-action="DeleteAll" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ArticleDetails.Count(); i++)
    {

        <input asp-for="ArticleDetails[i].ID" name="@("ddd["+ i + "].ID")" type="hidden" />

        <input asp-for="ArticleDetails[i].IsChecked" name="@("ddd["+ i + "].IsChecked")" />
    }

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```